# I want to install dlib without installing Visual Studio 19

Tags: python, opencv, pip, face-recognition, dlib

I've been trying to install **dlib** library for face recognition project but every time I'm trying to install the packages, an error occurs.

Is there any way I could work on using **face_recogniton** library and install dlib without using Visual Studio 2019 (Desktop Development for C++)?

Answer (score 0):

No way. Dlib [is distributed](https://pypi.org/project/dlib/19.21.1/#files) only in source form and there is no binary wheels so you have to [compile it from the sources](http://dlib.net/compile.html).

Answer (score 0):

First download Anaconda
then go to Environments Under Home click on create (bottom left) enter name of new environment ***(in packages make sure python version is 3.7)*** then click on create
then click on the new environment that you created then you will see (installed) change it to (Not installed) and type in search bar dlib it will show then click on it and click apply and it will install